# Automatically Creating A Zip after Code Signing in Xcode

Tags: xcode, build-process

I have a custom script step in my build process that zips the executable. However this is executing before the executable is signed which is pretty useless.

Is there a way to zip the build output after the code is signed, within the Xcode build process. I can certainly do it externally if i need to, but I'd like to make it part of my Xcode build script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you'd create an Aggregate Target that first builds your main target, then runs a Run Script Build Phase to postprocess it.